# django-plotly-dash serve css files locally

Tags: python, django, plotly-dash

I am trying to serve css files locally in a DjangoDash app using django-plotly-dash.

Simpleexample.py

```
app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample', serve_locally=True)
app.css.append_css("path_to_css")
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(
        className="app-header",
        children=[
            html.Div('Plotly Dash', className="app-header--title")
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(
        children=html.Div([
            html.H5('Overview'),
            html.Div('''
                This is an example of a simple Dash app with
                local, customized CSS.
            ''')
        ])
    )
])
```

simpleexample.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
{% load plotly_dash %}

    {% plotly_app name='SimpleExample' ratio=0.45 %}
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

header.css and topography.css are the files as described here: https://dash.plotly.com/external-resources.

According to these: https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/issues/121 and https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/issues/133, the issues regarding this should be fixed.

However the css styling does not render--

[image: browser image]

What am I missing here? There was a suggestion in the above github issues that we can use django template rather than iframe. I could not find much documentation on that -- can anyone point me there?

Thank you.

Comment: I tried app = DjangoDash('SimpleExample', external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets) as well with an url of external_styleshteets containing css files -- it did not work as well.

Comment: Finally solved it using plotly_direct tag. In case anyone is interested I found the documentations here -- https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst and https://django-plotly-dash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/template_tags.html.

Answer (score 2):

```
app = DjangoDash('Home',add_bootstrap_links=True)  
app.css.append_css({ "external_url" : "/static/assets/style.css" })
```

place your assets folder in Django static folder

If you get Python Error: No module named bootstrap4.bootstrap
try

```
    pip install "django_bootstrap4==1.1.1"
```

or

```
    pip install django_bootstrap4
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<!-- templates/base.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    ...
    {% load plotly_dash%}
    ...
    {% plotly_header %}
    ...
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
    {%plotly_direct name="SimpleExample"%}
    ...
    </body>
    ...
    {% plotly_footer %}
</html>
```