# Plotly Dash App in Django throws TypeError on __init__() Positional Arguments

Tags: python, django, dashboard, plotly-dash

I have been following the example here exactly

https://thinkinfi.com/integrate-plotly-dash-in-django/

it works fine if I set the virtual environment up with packages of the exact packages it has specified. However I am trying to follow this method and implement it into an existing Django project, so I would prefer to use the latest versions of the packages. With these versions instead

- django-plotly-dash==1.5.0
- dash==1.18.1
- dash-bootstrap-components==0.11.1
- dash-daq==0.5.0
- dpd-static-support==0.0.5
- whitenoise==5.2.0

I got this error

```
Exception inside application: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/staticfiles.py", line 44, in __call__
    return await self.application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 71, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 47, in __call__
    return await self.inner(dict(scope, cookies=cookies), receive, send)
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/sessions.py", line 254, in __call__
    return await self.inner(wrapper.scope, receive, wrapper.send)
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/auth.py", line 181, in __call__
    return await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/middleware.py", line 26, in __call__
    return await self.inner(scope, receive, send)
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 150, in __call__
    return await application(
  File "/home/jasontam/Personal/GitProjects/dashboard_django/newEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asgiref/compatibility.py", line 33, in new_application
    instance = application(scope)
TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve it? I have a similar setup going fine (except that I couldn't get it to use a local css file like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61126537/django-plotly-dash-serve-css-files-locally), and when I pre-load it into the html teamplate it conflicts with the one that I am using for nav and side bars, but that's a different problem) that I can compare with, and I have gone through the dash_app_code.py and labelled all of the div children arrays, in case it was where the difference is, unfortunately not though.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this error occurring when you update the packages, even with the same code from that website staying the same? Or, are you running different code and updated dependencies? You'll have to break things down until you can isolate what's at fault. Based on the version numbers changing, I would suspect it's one of these packages: `dash-bootstrap-components`, `dash-daq`, `dpd-static-support`.

Comment: @coralvanda Thanks for your comment. It is the exact same code running with different package versions. I was hoping that it is something simple and common that only a noob such as me would be troubled by it

Comment: Doesn't seem like a noob issue to me. Maybe try updating one dependency at a time and running to see if it works. Keep trying one at a time until you get the error. That should help you narrow down where this is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Read this link, they suggest a workaround...
https://github.com/GibbsConsulting/django-plotly-dash/issues/290

Basically:

1. `pip install channels_redis`
2. Go to the settings file.
3. Comment the 'channels' in the INSTALLED_APPS.
4. Add 'channels_redis' to the INSTALLED_APPS.

This worked for me.

PDT.
I tested with 2 different environments, and this error was fixed in both.

Environment 1:

```
django==4.0
django_plotly_dash==1.6.6
channels==3.0.4
channels_redis==3.3.1
bootstrap4==0.1.0
dpd_static_support==0.0.5
dash==1.20.0
dash_daq==0.5.0
dash_bootstrap_components==0.13.1
pandas==1.3.5
whitenoise==5.3.0
```

Environment 2

```
django==3.0.5
django_plotly_dash==1.1.4
channels==3.0.4
channels_redis==3.3.1
bootstrap4==0.1.0
dpd_static_support==0.0.5
dash==1.6.1
dash_daq==0.3.1
dash_bootstrap_components==0.7.2
pandas==1.1.5
whitenoise==5.0.1
```